# Just keep the first value of every minute in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to reduce my data. My initial dataframe looks as follows:

| index | time [hh:mm:ss] | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 days 00:00:00.000000 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 days 00:00:04.000000 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 days 00:02:02.002300 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | 0 days 00:02:03.000000 | 9 | 7 |
| 4 | 0 days 03:02:03.000000 | 4 | 3 |

Now I want to reduce my data in order to only keep the cells of every new minute (respectively also new hour and days). the other way around: only the first line of a new minute should be kept. all remaining lines of this minute should be dropped.
So the resulting table looks as follows:

| index | time | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 days 00:00:00.000000 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 days 00:02:02.002300 | 7 | 9 |
| 4 | 0 days 03:02:03.000000 | 4 | 3 |

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck at the moment? Please add a [mcve] to your code to make helping you easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is used timedeltas so is possible create `TimedeltaIndex` and use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `1Minute` with [`Resampler.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html), only are added all minutes, so removed only NaNs rows:

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df['time [hh:mm:ss]'])

df = df.resample('1Min').first().dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
          time [hh:mm:ss]  value1  value2
0  0 days 00:00:00.000000     3.0     4.0
1  0 days 00:02:02.002300     7.0     9.0
2  0 days 03:02:03.000000     4.0     3.0
```

Comment: Every time ask I appreciate your answers. Can you recommend a book/literature for pandas as a starting point? Or is it more like experience?

Comment: @AdlerMüller - For me working a lot of coding and then [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html), especially modern pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the D:HH:MM using apply and multiple splits, and then delete the duplicates, choosing the first value.

```
dms = df['time [hh:mm:ss]'].apply(lambda x: ':'.join( [x.split(' days ')[0], *x.split('days ')[1].split(':')[:2]]) )
df.iloc[dms.drop_duplicates().index]
```

Answer (score 0):

> d = '''index,time,value1,value2 0,0 days 00:00:00.000000,3,4 1,0 days
> 00:00:04.000000,5,2 2,0 days 00:02:02.002300,7,9 3,0 days
> 00:02:03.000000,9,7 4,0 days 03:02:03.000000,4,3'''
>
> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),parse_dates=True)

> df

[image]

> df['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.slice(7))
> df.set_index('time1',inplace=True)

> df

[image]

> df.groupby([df.index.hour,df.index.minute]).head(1).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

[image]